# How to copy a 200GB file faster?

Tags: rsync, copy, scp, copying

I got a 200GB .tgz file on server A(RHEL 5.2). I wanna transfer that file to server B (RHEL 5.3). Server B is on ESXi 4 Update1.  Server B VM is with 4 vCPUs, with 10GB RAM.

Both Server A and Server B are connected with an ethernet cable with local IP addies (no switch involved)

scp gives me about 3Mbps. Is there a way to get 400Mbps?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To be real down and dirty you can use netcat.

On the sender

```
cat {filename} | nc -l 3333
```

On the receiver

```
nc {sender_ip_address} 3333 > {filename}
```

Since there will be nearly no application overhead, you should only be limited by IO, whether disk or network.

Comment: +1 for netcat - the best tool for this kind of thing IMO

Comment: The proper syntax on the receive side is
`cat filename | nc -l -p 3333`

Otherwise it will silently bind a random port...

Comment: useless use of cat ;) nc -l 3333 < {filename}

Comment: @james:  Yeah, it's a personal preference thing.  Using cat is what I first learned and got used to.  Similarly, retraining myself to using 'sudo -i' instead of 'sudo su -' has been fun :)

Comment: @b0fh:  The -p option specifies source port, and the man page specifically points out that, "It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option."

Comment: @packs: Is this GNU netcat ? The original one uses -p for the local port, not the source port. (I don't know which version RHEL is shipping)

Answer (score 2):

Use an unencrypted transfer method that doesn't do compression. I'd suggest FTP, given how simple it is to setup and the lack of chatty protocol, like Samba

Answer (score 1):

Good points from Matt again, you might also consider ensuring you have the latest VMtools installed on Server B.

Answer (score 0):

You need a FTP server that supports Mode Z compression or bzip compression such as [NULL FTP Server](http://www.vwsolutions.com/NullFTPServer/) .   I don't know what the Linux equivilant would be.  With compression you can increase the efficiency/speed by up to 75%, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Compression over a LAN is a bad idea. The amount of time the CPU spends compressing the data could be better spent sending it across the wire.

Comment: I dunno. Most modern systems will do gzip compression (not bzip) at 100MB/sec+ - wire speed basically - so compression can be a net win depending on the data. We compress over the LAN for certain workloads and it actually speeds things up hugely.

Comment: Yes, except for he is transferring an already gzipped file. I assume he won't be able to get it any smaller.

Comment: Very good point